# Time each iterations of For Loop in Julia?

Tags: loops, for-loop, julia, expression, metaprogramming

Given a **for loop**, is there some macro/function that **times each iteration** of the loop, and returns this info as a tuple or array (or similar)? Would there be any way to assign such tuple or array to a variable (for example, I am not sure how to assign output of @time macro to a variable). I am aware of the **@timed** macro, but not sure how to extract the tuple that @timed gives/assign to variable. Below is an example of a for loop where each iteration might be timed?

```
 for x=1:10
     println("$x is my number.") 
 end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
function timeloop(n)
    tvec = zeros(n)
    for x = 1:n
        t = @elapsed println("$x is my number.")
        tvec[x] = t
    end
    tvec
end

timeloop(9)
1 is my number.
2 is my number.
3 is my number.
4 is my number.
5 is my number.
6 is my number.
7 is my number.
8 is my number.
9 is my number.

9-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0002649
 0.0001195
 0.0001018
 9.44e-5
 8.25e-5
 6.8e-5
 8.52e-5
 7.39e-5
 8.5e-5
```

As per Julia help, `@elapsed` is a macro to evaluate an expression, discarding the resulting value, instead returning the number of seconds it took to execute as a floating-point number.

For timing multi-line expressions/statements, use the `t = @elapsed begin .. end` form.